# TikZ: Pgf Plot not taking desired width

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, pgfplots, textwidth, linewidth

I want to have two 3D plots next to each other, one showing the 3D view of the plot, the other showing the top view. I pulled out the pictures to put them in a MWE that gives me the same wrong result (appended at the end).
I tried doing it with figures and subfigures but that also didn't work. My current approach is using a tabular environment with 2 `0.5\textwidth` columns and then have the width of the axes be `\linewidth` each.

I am a bit lost why the pictures are not taking half the textwidth each.

The MWE/Code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, ngerman, footsepline, headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}              
\usepackage{pgfplots}
% TIKZ settings
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% For debugging
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}

% Geometry of the target document
\geometry{nomarginpar, top=30mm, bottom=35mm, left=25mm, right=25mm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}[h]{@{}p{.5\textwidth}@{}p{.5\textwidth}@{}}
    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
                declare function = {
                        f(\x,\y) = (\x*\x - \y*\y)*exp(\x*\x - \y*\y);
                    },
            ]
            \begin{axis}[
                    xmin = -1.5, xmax = 1.5,
                    ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5,
                    axis lines = center,
                    domain=-1:1,
                    domain y=-1:1,
                    xlabel = {x},
                    ylabel = {y},
                    zlabel = {z},
                    scale mode=scale uniformly,
                    width = \linewidth,
                    colormap/viridis,
                ]
                % Add the base plots
                \addplot3[name path=functionf,
                    samples = 50,
                    samples y = 50,
                    contour filled={levels={0,0.25,0.5,1,5,10}},
                    shader=interp,
                    opacity=0.6]
                {f(x,y)};

                % Add the zero lines
                \addplot3[thick](x,x,0) node[pos=1,anchor=south west]{\(y=x\)};
                \addplot3[thick](x,-x,0) node[pos=1,anchor=north west]{\(y=-x\)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
     &
    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
                outer sep=0pt,
                declare function = {
                        f(\x,\y) = (\x*\x - \y*\y)*exp(\x*\x - \y*\y);
                    },
            ]
            \begin{axis}[
                    axis lines = center,
                    domain=-1:1,
                    domain y=-1:1,
                    view={0}{90},
                    xlabel = {x},
                    ylabel = {y},
                    zlabel = {z},
                    scale mode=scale uniformly,
                    width = \linewidth,
                    colormap/viridis,
                ]
                % Add the base plots
                \addplot3[name path=functionf,
                    samples = 50,
                    samples y = 50,
                    contour filled={levels={0,0.25,0.5,1,5,10}},
                    shader=interp,
                    opacity=0.6]
                {f(x,y)};

                % Add the zero lines
                \addplot3[thick](x,x,0) node[pos=0.8,anchor=south east]{\(y=x\)};
                \addplot3[thick](x,-x,0) node[pos=0.8,anchor=north east]{\(y=-x\)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Picture of how the MWE currently looks like (added a headline to visualize the textwidth):

[image: MWE example Image]

The jagged edges of the color is just rendering issues of the pdf viewer.

Comment: Your question is a good question but just a bit of advice, sometimes including images of how your code/MWE currently looks helps people, particularly with `tikz` questions :)

Comment: @JamesT Thanks for the hint. I'll quickly snap a screenshot of the pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, with a downside:

- scaling the canvas makes the left one larger
- any scale factor, even 1, seems to absorb the rules from the `fbox`
- this might be due to some margin settings; perhaps you'd introduce those rules in a more tikz-ish way?

[image: scaled]

```
\begin{tabular}[h]{@{}p{.5\textwidth}@{}p{.5\textwidth}@{}}
    \fbox{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=2},% <<<
                declare function = {
                        f(\x,\y) = (\x*\x - \y*\y)*exp(\x*\x - \y*\y);
                    },
```

Comment: The fbox is just for debugging purposes so that doesn't matter. Problem with your solution though is, that the text also gets scaled up. That makes both pictures not ahve the same textsize.

Comment: This problem is known in print-industry as well. Solution: provide images, which follow certain rules, to avoid such problems. Here it would be requirements for w and h of both images. // Perhaps there's another feature Tikz provides. E.g. you can just scale `\tikzpicture`s; if you forget to put `transform shape`, unexpected scaling happens. Perhaps you can use this effect for good, here?